# How to match contiguous character block of '>' on newline?

Tags: java, regex

I have the following file contents and I'm trying to match a reg-ex for contiguous blocks of a character (specifically '>') at the beginning of each line and remove that block of matching text:

```
-- file.txt (Before regx match and replace) -- 
keep this

> remove this
>
> remove this too
-- EOF -- 


-- file.txt (After regex mach and replace) -- 
keep this

-- EOF --
```

I'm trying to match this for multiline  (i.e. remove any line that starts with a '>'). Is this correct or the best approach?  The following doesn't seem to be working.

```
    // String text = <file contents from above...the Before contents>
    Pattern PATTERN = 
      Pattern.compile("^>(.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher m = PATTERN.matcher(text);
    if (m.find()) {
       // Matches each line starting with > and deletes (replaces with "") the line
       text = m.replaceAll("");  

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say it's not working?  What goes wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [`@Peter Alfvin`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1008891/peter-alfvin) stated, you need to include your line breaks `\n` in your replace.

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?m)^>[^>]*?\n", "");
```

Regular expression:

```
(?m)           set flags for this block (with ^ and $ matching start and end of line)
^              the beginning of a "line"
>              '>'
 [^>]*?        any character except: '>' (0 or more times)
               (matching the least amount possible))
 \n            '\n' (newline)
```

The `(?m)` modifier (multi-line) causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line.

See [`working demo`](http://ideone.com/8RKKLs)

Answer (score 2):

You need to match through the end-of-line (`\n`) and not just up to it (`$`) in order to get rid of those lines entirely.